# android camera classic API: writing a blocking (synchronous) 'takePicture()'

Tags: android, multithreading, camera

I'm writing an Android app and I need to take photos.  I got it mostly working very quickly using the standard tutorial.  But I need to write a blocking version of "takePicture()".  I've trying reworking my design so that everything is done asynchronously, but the code just ends up as spaghetti code because so many tasks are dependent on the previous task completing.  And I had expected that taking a photo would take less than a second.  So I think it's a reasonable goal to have a blocking (synchronous) "takePicture()".

So I created a camera in the UI thread (I'm an Android newbie but I presume that 'onCreate()' et al are called in the UI thread).  I also open the camera and release it in the UI thread.  I also call "takePicture()" in the UI thread.  I tried polling for a "volatile byte[] jpeg;" field to become non-null, with a "while (jpeg != null) sleep(1000);" but it never gets assigned.  To my surprise, my callback doesn't get called until I pass out of the "onClick()" function - 'takePicture()' doesn't seem to trigger anything, it merely queues something, as far as I can figure out.

My next attempt involved doing all the camera work (open, takePicture, release) in a "ExecutorService.newSingleThreadExecutor()" but that was also unsuccessful.  Even when I did it this way (see below), the callback wasn't called until the app finished the 'onClick()'.

```
public byte[] takePhoto()
{
    if (camera == null)
        return null;
    cameraThreadService.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                    jpeg = data;
                }
            };
            camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }
    });
    int n = 0;
    while (jpeg == null) {
        sleep(1000);
        if (n++ > 5)
            break;
    }
    return jpeg;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to write a blocking (synchronous) 'camera.takePicture()'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To my surprise, my callback doesn't get called until I pass out of the "onClick()" function - 'takePicture()' doesn't seem to trigger anything, it merely queues something, as far as I can figure out.

Your `onPictureTaken()` is called on the main application thread. The main application thread cannot do two things at once. `onPictureTaken()` cannot be called until after you return from `onClick()`.

> Can anyone tell me how to write a blocking (synchronous) 'camera.takePicture()'?

That is not possible, sorry.

Comment: "cameraThreadService.submit(new Runnable() { ...." would seem to imply that it's _not_ called on the main thread.

Comment: And are you saying that it's not possible to "sleep and loop" i.e. poll until a certain condition is met?  I would not be telling my employer that "that is not possible".

Comment: And what does 'trigger' mean, in the official documentation for 'takePicture()': "Triggers an asynchronous image capture."  ....?  It might make more sense if I understood what this meant in terms of threads.

Comment: @TimCooper: "And are you saying that it's not possible to "sleep and loop" i.e. poll until a certain condition is met?" -- not in your scenario. Besides, that's not a particularly good programming practice in the first place. "It might make more sense if I understood what this meant in terms of threads" -- `takePhoto()` is called on the main application thread. `onPictureTaken()` will be called on the main application thread. A thread cannot do two things at once.

Comment: @TimCooper: "would seem to imply that it's not called on the main thread" -- assuming that `cameraThreadService.submit()` invokes its `Runnable` on a background thread, all that does is call `takePicture()` on a background thread. It says nothing about where `onPictureTaken()` is called.